# Check if a line exists in a file

Tags: python

How can I check if a line exists in a file?

I'd also like to write the line to the file if it does not exist.

This is my current attempt:

```
logfile = open('ip.log', 'a+')

while 1:
    line = logfile.readline()
    #line.replace("\n", "")
    print line
        
    if line == str(self.CLIENT_HOST):
        print "Line Found Skipping"
    else:
        logfile.write(str(self.CLIENT_HOST)+"\n")
    if not line:
        print "EOF Reached"
        break
    print line
logfile.close()
```

Comment: As a note, you're better served using built-in functions like readlines() and using the for.. syntax. While (1) is much more error-prone.

Comment: You should not use while 1: at all.It is a magic number use. Instead, if needed use while True:.

Comment: @Andrej: I agree. However, merely as a curiosity, `while 1:` is actually more efficient in Python 2, because `True` does a lookup (it's not a reserved word as it is in Python 3) while `1` is known to be true - so the bytecode is formed actually not creating a block for `while 1:`. To observe, create your functions and compare `dis.dis(func)`.

Comment: @Chris: Interesting! I remember reading once about the genealogy of True in python, but I didn't know about this. One more reason to go to Python3 I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
logfile = open('ip.log', 'r')
loglist = logfile.readlines()
logfile.close()
found = False
for line in loglist:
    if str(self.CLIENT_HOST) in line:
        print "Found it"
        found = True

if not found:
    logfile = open('ip.log', 'a')
    logfile.write(str(self.CLIENT_HOST)+"\n")
    logfile.close()
```

This is my first quick solution. Very unclean and not yet sophisticated, but should work.

Comment: *Very* unclean and inefficient.

Answer (score 8):

To append to the log file a client host string if it is not already present you could:

```
with open('ip.log', 'r+') as f:
     for line in f:
         if self.CLIENT_HOST in line:
            break
     else: # not found
         print >>f, self.CLIENT_HOST
```

Note: the indentation of the `else` statement is not an error. It is a Python feature to allow `for` and `while` loops to have an `else` clause. It is run if `break` statement is not executed inside the loop.

Comment: Totally underrated and in my opinion classy solution. Thank you.

Comment: mode should be "r+" with "a+" it does'nt work for me in Python3

Comment: @tamerlaha `print >>f, ..` suggests it is a Python 2 code. Though `r+` seems like it should fit better.

Answer (score 7):

I think this should work, and it's neater and more robust than any of the other answers yet. If it doesn't, then you may need to open another file for writing (first file `'r'`, second file `'a'`). Also I've gone for using `x.rstrip('\r\n')` and `==` rather than `in` to make sure it's correct. I don't know what your `CLIENT_HOST` variable is. If your `CLIENT_HOST` is already a str, throw away the first line and change the others back to referencing it directly.

```
value = str(self.CLIENT_HOST)
with open('ip.log', 'a+') as f:
    if not any(value == x.rstrip('\r\n') for x in f):
        f.write(value + '\n')
```

Comment: OS X may need an additional f.seek(0) because file pointer is at the end of the file after opening in "a+" mode.

Comment: This should actually apply to all OS. According to the docs the file pointer is at the end of the file, at least for Python 3 https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 2):

Use python filter:

```
file = open('ip.log', 'r')
flines = file.readlines()
res = filter(lambda x: self.CLIENT_HOST in x, flines)
if len(res) == 0:
  file.write(str(self.CLIENT_HOST)+"\n")
  file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change open('ip.log', 'a+') to open('ip.log', 'r'), then write the file again later or write to a new file. Otherwise you are just making the file infinitely longer.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the lines allows you to stop loading the file when you find a match, and prevents you from having to hold the entire file in memory.

```
def log_host(self):
    host = str(self.CLIENT_HOST)

    with open('ip.log', 'r+') as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            if line.strip() == host:
                return

        # Move to the end of the file:
        logfile.seek(0, 2)
        logfile.write(host + "\n")
```

Comment: Wouldn't you already be at the end of the file because you just read every line?

Answer (score 0):

might be something like this

```
line="the line you are searching for"

logfile = open('ip.log', 'r')
loglist = logfile.readlines()
logfile.close()

if line not in loglist:
    loglist.append(line)

new_logfile = open("pathToTheFile/logfile", 'w')
for lines in loglist:
    new_logfile.write(lines)
```