# Extract fasta files from ID list with Biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I am using Biopython to find sequences in a fasta file that match IDs from a .txt file comprising selected IDs. When searching for the ID names in the fasta file manually I do get hits, but the following script doesn't find/extract any sequences:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from Bio import SeqIO
wanted_ids = "transcript.orthogroup7.txt"
input_filename = "hq_isoseq_transcripts.fasta"
output_filename = "wanted_hq_isoseq_transcripts.fasta"
count = 0
total = 0
output_handle = open(output_filename, "w")
for record in SeqIO.parse(input_filename, "fasta"):
    total = total + 1
    if record.id in wanted_ids:
        count = count + 1
        SeqIO.write(record, output_handle, "fasta")
output_handle.close()
print(str(count) + " records selected out of " + str(total))
```

Here is an excerpt from the .fasta file

```
>20190807-P1_PBI19-RO01_8pM_HQ_transcript/0
GGTACGTATAGGAATTATAAGGGCTCATTGAGACAGTCTGAGCAAAAAAGTCTCGTTCAG
GCTCGCTAAAAGCCTTTGGTGACGCATCTGTCCGTGAGCGAGTCACATTTTGTGAGCGAG
TCACGAATCTCGGCGCCGGCGAATCATGAATCTCCGTAACAGTGAGTCGCGAATCTCCTA
AGCCGTGTGTTTTGCGCACGTCACTTCATTCCTCGGTACAGGGCTTCCTCTTAACAGGAA ... and so on
>20190807-P1_PBI19-RO01_8pM_HQ_transcript/1
GACTATATAGGAATTATAAGGGCTCATTGAGACAGTCTGAGCAAAAAAGTCTCGTTCAGG
CTCGCTAAAAGCCTTTGGTGACGCATCTGTCCGTGAGCGAGTCACATTTTGTGAGCGAGT
CACGAATCTCGGCGCCGGCGAATCATGAATCTCCGTAACAGTGAGTCGCGAATCTCCTAA
GCCGTGTGTTTTTGCGCACGTCACTTCATTCCTCGGTACAGGGCTTCCTCTCAGCAGGAA ... and so on
```

and my ID .txt file

```
>20190807-P1_PBI19-RO01_8pM_HQ_transcript/0
>20190807-P1_PBI19-RO01_8pM_HQ_transcript/1
```

I execute the script in a conda environment and get the following unexpected message

```
(biopython_transcripts) $ python3 script.py
0 records selected out of 35629
```

When changing the "count" and "total" to for example 1000, I get

```
(biopython_transcripts) $ python3 script.py
1000 records selected out of 35629
```

So the script runs but doesn't extract any sequences despite I am positive that the sequences exist and that the names in the .txt and the .fasta file match completely.

I am open to other solutions than Biopython but would really appreciate help with understanding why this doesn't work and possible solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if a line exists in a file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775106/check-if-a-line-exists-in-a-file-python)

Comment: You are checking whether the ids are contained in the *filename* which they are obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the file with the wanted ids and build a list of the ids to keep. Currently, your code checks the ids against the **file name** of the wanted ids (i.e. if would match only if an ids is a substring of `transcript.orthogroup7.txt`)

Here is a modification of your code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
wanted_filename = "transcript.orthogroup7.txt"           ## changed name
input_filename = "hq_isoseq_transcripts.fasta"
output_filename = "wanted_hq_isoseq_transcripts.fasta"
count = 0
total = 0
output_handle = open(output_filename, "w")

with open(wanted_filename) as f:                         ## added lines to
    wanted_ids = [l[1:-1] for l in f]                    ## build list of ids
## now wanted_ids = ['20190807-P1_PBI19-RO01_8pM_HQ_transcript/0', '20190807-P1_PBI19-RO01_8pM_HQ_transcript/1']

for record in SeqIO.parse(input_filename, "fasta"):
    total = total + 1
    if record.id in wanted_ids:
        count = count + 1
        SeqIO.write(record, output_handle, "fasta")
output_handle.close()
print(str(count) + " records selected out of " + str(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the ideas in the mozway's code to make a "fasta sequences grep"

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO
try:
        seq_file =open(sys.argv[1])
        seq_list = (sys.argv[2])
#Normal grep
        with open(seq_list) as f:
            wanted_ids = [l[1:-1] for l in f]
        if len(sys.argv) == 3:
            for record in SeqIO.parse(seq_file, "fasta"):
                if record.id in wanted_ids:
                    print(">",record.id,"\n",record.seq,sep ='')
#Inverse grep if third -v argv provided
        if len(sys.argv) == 4 and sys.argv[3] == "-v":
            for record in SeqIO.parse(seq_file, "fasta"):
                if not record.id in wanted_ids:
                    print(">",record.id,"\n",record.seq,sep ='')
        if len(sys.argv) == 4 and sys.argv[3] != "-v":
            print("For inverse grep use -v (optional)",sep ='')
except:
    print("Usage:","grep_fasta_names.py <file.fasta> <ids.txt> -v (optional inverse grep) > output.fasta",sep = '')
```